# Trouble with collapsing factor on y axis in ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, geom-bar, yaxis

I am having a problem. My ggplot keeps collapsing two equally named vectors into one and I would like to have it as two separate bars labeled QVAR REDIHALER and the rest of the labels of course.

```
data.frame(
brand_name = c("QVAR REDIHALER", "QVAR REDIHALER", "XARELTO", "XIFAXAN", "LATUDA", "TRINTELLIX", "VYVANSE", "NUCYNTA"),
n = c(78, 48, 71, 26, 8, 5, 8, 1))



brand_name1 %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = reorder(brand_name, (-n)), y = n, fill = brand_name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), hjust = -1) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank()) +
  ylab("Count") +
  xlab("") +
  labs(fill = "Brand name", title = "Top Rebate Eligable - Brand") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  coord_flip()
```

The issue is where the arrow is pointed. I would like to have "QVAR REDIHALER" repeat twice as in data frame instead of it collapsing to one bar

[image]

Comment: What's that complex about providing a sample dataset which according to your image and code contains only 8 rows and 2 columns? Anyway. What you mean by split? You want two separate columns? In that case recode the duplicated category to get separate bars. If you require the same labels on the axis you could do so via the labels argument of scale_y_discrete.

Comment: @stefan . You are actually right I can provide the columns needed rest of it I can exclude. Thank you for the help. I tried with scale_y_discrete and it does not work. I have the same problem again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure about how you want to split the duplicated category into two columns. But I give it a try.

One option would be to make the duplicated categories unique by using a helper column e.g. adding a number 1, 2, ... to each and mapping this helper column on `y`. Doing so you get separate columns. To get rid of the numbers showing up on the axis labels you could make use of a labeller function via `scale_y_discrete`, i.e. use e.g. `gsub` to remove the numbers:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

brand_name1 <- brand_name1 %>% 
  group_by(brand_name) %>% 
  mutate(brand_name_uniq = paste0(brand_name, row_number()))

ggplot(brand_name1, mapping = aes(x = reorder(brand_name_uniq, (-n)), y = n, fill = brand_name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), hjust = -1) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = ~gsub("\\d$", "", .x)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank()) +
  ylab("Count") +
  xlab("") +
  labs(fill = "Brand name", title = "Top Rebate Eligable - Brand") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Worked as a charm. I think I misused that verb split. Basically, I would like each factor (character) to have its own value and not group it. Thank you